# Python: code at module level not executed when imported

Tags: python, import

module 1: abc.py

```
print "abc"
```

module 2: xyz.py

```
import abc
```

As the print is not part of any class or function, I was expecting running the xyz.py module would cause "abc" to be printed (as part of importing that module), which is not the case. What's going on and what do i need to do to so "abc" will be printed out when running xyz.py?

Comment: You're probably importing [the `abc` module from the stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) by accident. Make sure you're importing the correct file.

Comment: Yes, that's indeed the case. It works as expected after I renamed the file, thanks